# Mouseout/hoverout in a Fancybox gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Anyone know how to find out if the mouse leaves a picture in a Fancybox gallery?

What I'm trying to do is to open the gallery when I mouse over a thumbnail image (which works fine), and then close the gallery with $.fancybox.close() when the mouse leaves the gallery picture that appeared.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a listener on #fancybox-wrap, but you will have to add this listener only after the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) it bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements, .

```
$("#yourImageSelector").hover(function(){

//open gallery

},
function(){


//close gallery


});
```

**Edit:**
for that see the second answer... [here](http://fancybox.net/blog) is an example see the 3rd part *Show/hide title on hover*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How could I get this to work **only** for the gallery, and not for the thumbnails? 

I make the gallery with:
`$("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox({ default settings});`

And this is how I open the images:
`$("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox().hover(function() {
        $(this).click();
    });`
However if I add the hover out function to the last bit code, it will happen when the gallery pops up.

Any idea how to make it work only for the gallery?

The images are shown like this:
`<a rel="gallery" href="30.jpg" title=""><img class="galleryImage" alt="" src="30.jpg"></a>`

Comment: Ahh, I feel stupid for not seeing that example even though I visited the page earlier. I just tried various other things than fancybox-wrap, like fancybox-content and image which didn't work.